# DropDownList bug - OnSelectedIndexChanged fires only when DDL is filled in HTML

Tags: asp.net, postback, html-select, autopostback, selectedindexchanged

Step 1. The DropDownList is filled with items on Page_Load.

Step 2. I select an item and it initiates postback. During this postback Page refreshes first, then OnSelectedIndexChanged fires and "ddl1_Select" function runs.

If I statically fill the DropDownList with data in Aspx (HTML) file, it works properly.
But, if I fill it in code-behind, the OnSelectedIndexChanged event never fires and DDL1_Select procedure doesn't start. Page just posts back and skips my procedure. Why doesn't this event fire and how to make it work?

**ASPX:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="mypage.aspx.cs" Inherits="mypage" Title="mypage" EnableViewState="False" %>

...

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_Select" AutoPostBack="True"/>
```

**ASPX.CS:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddl1.Items.Add("1");
    ddl1.Items[0].Value = "1";
    ddl1.Items.Add("2");
    ddl1.Items[1].Value = "2";
    ddl1.Items.Add("3");
    ddl1.Items[2].Value = "3";

    if (Session["NewSelection"] != null) // see note 1
    {
        string itemValue = Session["NewSelection"].ToString();
        ddl1.SelectedIndex = ddl1.Items.IndexOf(ddl1.Items.FindByValue(itemValue));
        Session["NewSelection"] = null; // see note 1
    }
}

protected void DDL1_Select(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["NewSelection"] = ddl1.SelectedValue;
    Page.Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx?test=" + Session["NewSelection"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
{ 
    ddl1.Items.Add("1");
    ddl1.Items[0].Value = "1";
    ddl1.Items.Add("2");
    ddl1.Items[1].Value = "2";
    ddl1.Items.Add("3");
    ddl1.Items[2].Value = "3";

    if (Session["NewSelection"] != null) // see note 1
    {
        string itemValue = Session["NewSelection"].ToString();
        ddl1.SelectedIndex = ddl1.Items.IndexOf(ddl1.Items.FindByValue(itemValue));
        Session["NewSelection"] = null; // see note 1
    }
}
}
```